# Try to Export Several CSV's without using separate code for each one

Tags: r, csv, matrix

I have many matrices with similar names. These matrices are the results of simulations that take hours to run. I want to be able to preserve these simulated results, so I can go about conducting an analysis. I do NOT want to have to run the simulations everyday in order to generate the results again, to continue my analysis. Therefore, I have decided to export each matrix as a csv. But, I am hoping there is an easy way to export ALL of my matrices as individual csv's instead of typing this code over and over

```
write.csv(mymatrix1, file="mymatrix1")
```

The matrix names might be revelant for a possible solution. Every matrix starts with "sample." After the period is a unique number.

I was thinking of some sort of loop, or possibly the use of a Wild Card? I don't know... Thanks!

Comment: what is inside `mymatrix1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the matrices are all in R:

```
for(i in ls(pattern="sample.")) {
    write.csv(i, file=paste(i,".csv",sep=""))
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This seemed like the easiest and most straight forward approach.

Comment: Is there a way to add a few characters to 'i' inside the write.csv command. For example, if i = sample21, and I wanted to have it named sample21rocks when it was written as a csv, how would I alter the write.csv command to do this?

Comment: You can change the middle line to include anything you like in the `paste` command, such as: `write.csv(i, file=paste(i,".rocks.csv",sep=""))` would then give you "sample.21.rocks.csv".

Answer (score 1):

as you said, you can do a loop the task that you want. Here is a small exmaple:

```
 sample.1<-matrix(0,ncol=10,nrow=10)
 sample.2<-matrix(0,ncol=10,nrow=10)
 sample.3<-matrix(0,ncol=10,nrow=10)



 for( i in 1:3){

   matname<-paste0("sample.",i)
   write.csv(get(matname),file=paste0(matname,".csv"))

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can construct the name using `sprintf` function. Then it's just a matter of fetching the object.

```
my.obj <- sprintf("sample%s", i) # i would be a variable you can control
write.csv(get(my.obj), file = paste(my.obj, ".csv", sep = ""))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have your file names, you can put them in a vector, and then call sapply in order to recursively call write.csv.

```
names <- c(a, b, c)

sapply(names, function(x) write.csv(x, file=as.character(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `get` and a `for` loop to save them

```
for (i in 1:num_samples)
    write.csv(get(paste0('sample.',i)),file=paste0('mymatrix',i))
```